# IQueryable: Select new triggers eager loading?

Tags: c#, linq, select, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to understand how linq queries are executed.

As I know `IQueryable` queries are evaluated on server side together with filters and select and are executed only when `ToList()` or `First()` method is called.

However I'm having troubles understanding how the following query is evaluated. Is the "select new" evaluated on client side or on server side?

Is the `Select(x=> new Note)` triggers eager loading ?

```
IQueryable<Note> query = db.Notes
                           .Where(x => Id == someId)
                           .Select(c => new Note 
                                            {
                                                Title = x.Title
                                                Id = x.NoteId,
                                            });
```

Comment: It's not really executed on the server side. On the client side it forms a corresponding SQL query and sends this. In your case the select statement defines the table columns to retrieve (Title and NoteId) and the object will be created on the client side.

Comment: Like Oliver said everything is executed on client-side, `IQueryable` there simply delays the execution to when needed. So your projection (`Select`) will be taken onto account in generated SQL

Comment: See the duplicate(s). The key is that the *entire* expression (`query`) is translated into SQL. The SQL is executed by the database. But also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: @GertArnold, why forced to close? just prepared explanation, which is not related to  documentation which explains nothing.

Comment: @paradise When the execution will happen ?

Comment: @GertArnold I don t understand the following statement from documentation: "EF Core supports partial client evaluation in the top-level projection (essentially, the last call to Select())."

Comment: @Svyatoslav Closing serves as building a system of signposts that point to more content. I thinks it's justified here. Maybe you can add your answer to the duplicate so it'll be visible to a larger audience (landing here and on the other question).

Comment: @JulieG If in the last `Select` there's code that can't be translated into SQL, EF will still translate everything before it into SQL, get that data from the database, and execute the last `Select` in memory (= client-side). This may happen if you do something like `Select(x => x.MapToDto(x))`, where `MapToDto` is a C# method.

Comment: @GertArnold understood. Shouldn' t I get translation exception for  your described scenario?.. Can a part of query be executed in memory and still (query) be of  type IQuerable?

Comment: @GertArnold Also I was wondering when the mapping to object Note is happening.                                   Thank you.

Comment: @JulieG, create new question, this one is dead. I have prepared answer, but moderators won't read questions accurately.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Alright, reopened since you insisted. What kept you from answering the duplicate question? It should apply there as well. BTW, please don't stimulate people to ask a new question just because you don't like it to have been closed. If there's something you don't like, flag a question for moderator attention. Or bring it to [meta].

Comment: @JulieG It will be executed when you'll access to `query` variable content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `Select new` is a instruction how to map DbDataReader fields to `Note` object. Member access parts like `x.Title` is translated to reader instruction like `dbReader.GetString(0)`.

Internally LINQ Translator generates SQL for retrieving data

```sql
SELECT 
    x.Title,
    x.NoteId
FROM Notes x
WHERE x.Id = @someId
```

And generates `LambdaExpression` (schematically)

```cs
(DbDataReader dr) => new Note
{
    Title = dr.GetString(0),
    Id = dr.GetInt32(1)
}
```

Then this `LambdaExpression` is compiled and cached. When LINQ Provider executes query via `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, etc, generated SQL is sent to the Database and starts process of enumerating DataReader. For each DataReader record applied above compiled lambda. It makes from `IQueryable<Note>` (server side) `IEnumerable<Note>` (client side).

This is VERY simple explanation what is done under hood.

Comment: Thank you @SvyatoslavDanyliv. It's answering my question. If you don't mind, could you provide some resources which will help to broaden my  knowledge.

Comment: As I know there is no literature about that. Some articles. Everything I know from currently exists LINQ providers, like `EF Core`, `linq2db` (which I support) and [Relinq](https://github.com/re-motion/Relinq) based `NHibernate` or others. If you plan to create your own LINQ provider better to look closer at `Relinq` it simplifies things a lot.